# Mouse hovering not happening in selenium with JAVA

Tags: hover, mouse

Mouse hovering not happening on both chrome and FF.
Below is the code I have used.

Can anybody help me.

```
//WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
//driver.get("http://demo.pickframes.com");
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\Chrome Driver\\chromedriver.exe");
ChromeDriver driver= new ChromeDriver();
Actions builder=new Actions(driver);
driver.get("http://demo.pickframes.com");
Thread.sleep(6000);
WebElement shop=driver.findElement(By.linkText("SHOP"));
builder.moveToElement(shop).perform();
Thread.sleep(2000);
driver.findElement(By.linkText("CANVAS")).click();
```